# What do "x.this" and "x.class" mean? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, class, this

I know what "this" means, but what does it mean when you put it behind the name of a class, or if you put ".class" behind the name of a class as in the code below?

Someone please explain

`Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);`

Comment: `ActivityA.this` is a *qualified this*. You use it in an inner class if you want to refer to the current instance of the containing class.

Comment: if you use kotlin, you can use, this@ActivityA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActivityA.this` refers to `this` of the enclosing class (`ActivityA`).

`ActivityB.class` simply refers to the `ActivityB` [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) reference.

Answer (score 0):

It means `this`. It's useful for Lambdas, nested classes, etc..

Comment: What makes you say that `this` is useful for lambdas, particularly?

Comment: OP asked: "I know what "this" means, *but what does it mean when you put it behind the name of a class*", to which you answered "It means `this`", but that doesn't look.. enough or even correct. Could you add more details to your answer and explain how `ActivityA.this` is different than only `this`?

Comment: Also your answer doesn't address `ActivityB.class`.